# NoMethodError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nomethoderror

I am getting

```
NoMethodError in ProjectsController#edit
undefined method `projects' for
#<User:0x28356d8>`app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:154:in `correct_user'
```

The params are: `{"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}`

The offending line in the `projects_controller` is:`@project = current_user.projects.find_by_id(params[:id])` as part of

```
def correct_user
   @project = current_user.projects.find_by_id(params[:id])
   redirect_to show_user_path if @project.nil?
end
```

My projects_controller#edit method is:

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.current_step = @project.first_step
  @user = current_user
end
```

This is being triggered by a button,

```
<%= link_to image_tag('img_blank.png'), edit_user_project_path(current_user), :class => "btn_edit_project" %>
```

with the HTML output as:

```
<a class="btn_edit_project" href="/users/1/projects/1/edit"><img src="/assets/img_blank.png" alt="Img_blank"></a>
```

My routes file contains the following:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects
end
```

and `rake routes` shows:

```
edit_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)      projects#edit
```

This problem keeps surfacing in different forms, but never quit gets resolved.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you declare an association between a user and a project? like `has_many :projects` in your user model?

Comment: @jvnill - Yes.  User model has `has_one :project` and Project model has `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: that's where the error is. you are using `current_user.projects` when it only has one project.

Comment: @jvnill I changed it to be `@project=current_user.project.find_by_id([params[:id])` and it throws a `NoMethodError, undefined method find_by_id`.

Comment: if a user has only one project, then current_user.project should be enough. no need for the project id

Comment: @jvnill I take that out and I get the NoMethodError on `first_step` in the project.rb model.  All this was working last week, and I added a new model to the app.  I think I need to go back to my last merge/commit and start over.  I don't have the forensics abilities to figure this out.

Comment: @jvnill - however, you did answer the question.  I learned something, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jvnill for the answer...

The association between the user and the project is a 1 to 1.  The user `has_one :project` and the project `belongs_to :user`.  As @jvnill pointed out, there is no need to qualify the lookup with `.find_by_id(params[:id])` because the user_id will only be in the projects table once and Rails can find it.